# Facebook App loading blank page

Tags: facebook

I created an app on facebook, for my website. Now it loads for my but not for any one else, it just loads a blank page, so obviously ive done something wrong but i cant figure out what 
any help would be great

here is the link to the app 
http://apps.facebook.com/112963092176394/?fb_source=search&ref=ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page doesn't have secure version served over HTTPS, so it fails for everyone who use "Secure Browsing" option on Facebook.

NOTE: SSL certificate is a requirement as of October 2011.

Comment: It fails even when they dont connect using a secure server I have tried it using a different facebook account and its not working there either

Comment: I Think i have fixed it my hosting provider says they dont offer a dedicated ssl unless i wish to pay for it (which i dont) so i have a shared ssl will that work the same way?
I have also updated the Secure Canvas URL:to direct to the ssl address the host gave me should this work now?

Comment: If the domain of "Secure Canvas URL" is listed as one of Application Domains everything should work as expected. It's working now for users browsing over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox gives the following message regarding your SSL certificate when trying to connect to https://www.exoticsworld.co.uk/?fb_source=search&ref=ts:

> **Secure Connection Failed**
>
> An error occurred during a connection to www.exoticsworld.co.uk.
>
> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

So see to it that you’l get that fixed. Ask your server admin (or whoever installed that certificate for you), if you don’t know what this is all about.